# Font-awesome do not work for me

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I copied font-awesome.min.css into my /Content folder and have the following lines in the Head of the test page:

```
<link href="/content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
<link href="/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Both CSS are loaded into the page (when using Developer tools Network). But none of the icons are shown on the test page.  I tried the following:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-align-left"></i></a>
  <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-align-center"></i></a>
  <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-align-right"></i></a>
  <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
</div>
```

Or many others from the examples on Awesome Fonts site. But nothing works.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the `.fa` class on the `<i>` tag as well, for example: 
`<i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>`

Comment: Josh, first, thank you.  The .fa classes show in the intellisense. But no image appears on the page.  Do I need to include some .font or .svg file into the project?

Comment: You're welcome Hidalgo. You shouldn't have to load any other files. Most of the fonts I see start with fa-... are you sure you have the icon name correct?

Comment: My version of Bootstrap is 3.0.3.  Should this version work with Font-Awesome?

Comment: Josh, I do know that the icon names are correct since in the IE Development tools I can see the classes.  That is, the "rectangle" of the image appears but no image.  And I copied your example in your post too.. But so far to no avail.

Comment: Ok gotcha so it's a rendering problem then. Let me do some research.

Comment: By the way, the example Fiddles I found in other posts where Font-Awesome was discussed work. Therefore, I don't see it as a problem with my IE (which is 10). And I tried in Chrome with the same negative results.  Thank you.

Comment: The reason I was asking about need for maybe other files is that I see in my download of font-awesome-4.0.3 folders .css and .fonts. But I didn't copy any files from the .fonts folder into my visual studio solution.

Comment: The problem is definitely with my copy of font-awesome.css.  When I use the cdn copy of the font-awesome.css everything works. That is, if I put the line <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">   in the Head of my page, the images show. So I need to figure how I downloaded a wrong copy of .css

Comment: Last post: the problem is that the project must have the .fonts folder and the files in this folder. Font-awesome appear to work just like Bootstrap: you include the .css file but it "uses" the files in other folders.